# unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown -- JAVA Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am building a Java app in JSF that makes a request to an API gets a JSON and fills a table with the JSON info...

This is the code:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "logic", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Logic  {

static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
static JSONObject jo = null;
static JSONArray cat = null;


public void connect()  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  try {   
 URL url = new URL("xxx");
 URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;

 while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
     System.out.println(inputLine);
     sb.append(inputLine+"\n");
     in.close();

 }






 }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
    cat = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
    jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(0);
    jo.get("cif");

    System.out.println(jo.get("cif"));
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}




private String cif;



final static private  ArrayList<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(jo.get("cif").toString())));



public ArrayList<Logic> getLogics() {
    return logics;
}

public Logic() {

}

public Logic(String cif) throws ParseException {
    this.cif = cif;
    connect();
}

public String getCif() {
    return cif;
}

public void setCif(String cif) {
    this.cif = cif;
}




}
```

On line 67 -> `final static private  ArrayList<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(jo.get("cif").toString())));`

it gives me this error in Netbeans: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.
I tried surrounding it in try catch but it gives other errors in other parts of code...what can I do so I can run app ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*I tried surrounding it in try catch but it gives other errors in other parts of code*" how and what?

Comment: the line that gives me errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you tried something like

```
try {
    final static private  ArrayList<Logic> logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(jo.get("cif").toString())));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is, that line is not inside a method, and you can't use `try...catch` there.

A quick way to solve this is to put that initialization in a `static` block

```
public class Logic {
    final static private  ArrayList<Logic> logics;


    static {
        try {
            logics = new ArrayList<Logic>(Arrays.asList(new Logic(jo.get("cif").toString())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // rest of your class...
}
```

But honestly I have to wonder why you declared `logics` as `static`. It's not apparent from the rest of your code. Also, I see you have a non-static `getLogics()` method. So I'd say, if there's really no reason to declare it as `static`, just make it non-static and initialize it in the constructor, where you can use `try...catch` to your heart's content.